# Integrating sql,pandas alongwith Bokeh

Tags: pandas, bokeh, pandasql

Here we are trying to load packages and then write an SQl query to integrate with Pandas and then finally using Bokeh to show the plot But bokeh is not showing anything.

You can consider the following as the dataset `df_new_2`:

```
             name       success_rate        failure_rate
             A          94.7                5.3
             B          94.3                5.7
             C          91                  9
             D          88                  13
             E          84                  16
             F          81                  19
             G          78                  22  
             H          74.6               25.4
```

## The code starts here

```
 import pandas.io.sql
 import pandas as pd
 import pyodbc
 from bokeh import mpl
 from bokeh.plotting import output_file,show 

 server = 'root'     #getting the server to work
 db = 'y'            #assigning database

 # Create the connection
 conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=localhost;PORT= 3306;DATABASE=y;UID=root;PWD=123456789;")
 cursor=conn.cursor()

 # query db- Here we are trying to count the number of success in a table and the name for which the success has been found by joining tables 
sql = """

   SELECT count(*) AS TOTAL,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN status=0 THEN 1 END) AS success,
   b.name
   FROM a
   JOIN b
   ON b.id=a.merchant
   GROUP BY merchant

   LIMIT 10
   """

  df = pandas.io.sql.read_sql(sql, conn)    #defining df as query result
  df.head()

  df_new=df.set_index('name')   #indexing as the name of a
  df_new['success_rate']=df_new['success']*100/df_new['TOTAL'] 
  df_new['failure_rate']=100-df_new['success_rate']     #assigning failure rate
  df_new2=pd.DataFrame(df_new,columns=['success_rate','failure_rate'])
  p=df_new2.plot(kind='barh',stacked=True)
  output_file("pandas_series.html", title="pandas_series.py example")   #assigning the name of output screen
  show(mpl.to_bokeh)   #showing the output of bokeh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got something a bit more useful for you now. Had to avoid mpl as I couldn't get that to work. One possible reason is that I don't think horizontal bar charts are available in bokeh.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Bar
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, show 
from bokeh.charts.operations import blend
from bokeh.charts.attributes import cat, color

df_new2 = pd.DataFrame({'Success Rate' : [94.7,94.3,91,88,84,81,78,74.6], 'Failure Rate' : [5.3,5.7,9,12,16,19,22,25.4]})
df_new2['inds'] = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']

p = Bar(df_new2, 
        values=blend('Failure Rate','Success Rate', name='% Success/Failure', labels_name='stacked'),
        label=cat('inds'),
        stack=cat(columns='stacked', sort=False),
        color=color(columns='stacked', palette=['Red', 'Green'],
                              sort=False),
                  legend='top_right',
                  title="Success Rate vs. Failure Rate")
output_file("pandas_series.html", title="pandas_series.py example")   #assigning the name of output screen
show(p)   #showing the output of bokeh
```

Comment: Had the line you pointed out be wrong, then pandas would have not given a plot. But pandas is giving a plot but bokeh is not able to transform it. I made the changes you mentioned and even then its the same result. Bokeh is still not transforming the plot

Comment: And why will my line present an error? Its just making a new dataframe with the name df_new2 with the same values as df_new and choosing only the columns that i mentioned. It is working fine i checked it again.

Comment: Yeah apologies, was using a slightly different example dataframe. Could you upload a data sample (e.g. 5-10 lines)?

Comment: You can consider this one as the data set df_new2 :-                                          name  success_rate  failure_rate
A  94.7   5.3
B  94.3   5.7
C  91   9
D   88   13
E  84   16
F  81   19
G  78   22 
H  74.6   25.4

Comment: got this error "Unable to save object of type '<class 'matplotlib.container.BarContainer'>'"

Comment: are you using the four import statements I just added?

Comment: Can you tell me where is the source from which i can read these things?

Comment: I took most of it from here http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/gallery/stacked_bar_chart.html

Bokeh seems quite well documented. If you could accept my answer that would be great btw :)